# Getting copy of 1947 marriage licence in Georgia (USA)

Tags: 20th-century, marriage-records, 1940s, georgia-usa

My parents got married in 1947 somewhere in Georgia, in August. I have looked everywhere for a copy of their marriage licence.. where should I be looking?

**Herbert Eugene MCNUTT**  4-26-1929 BORN IN KNOXVILLE TN..     Died 11/26/1984

> "Find A Grave Index," database, FamilySearch
>   (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QV2V-GYPF : 13 December
>   2015), Herbert E McNutt, 1984; Burial, Knoxville, Knox, Tennessee,
>   United States of America, Cemetery of Meridian Baptist Church; citing
>   record ID 67137780, Find a Grave, http://www.findagrave.com.

**Myrtle Ruth PACK**       2-13-1931 BORN IN KNOXVILLE TN        Died 2-9-1985

> "Find A Grave Index," database, FamilySearch
>   (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QVPQ-PPB2 : 13 December
>   2015), Myrtle Pack McNutt, 1985; Burial, Knoxville, Knox, Tennessee,
>   United States of America, Woodlawn Cemetery; citing record ID
>   135972613, Find a Grave, http://www.findagrave.com.

---

They got married in Georgia  because they were under age and their Mothers went with them and signed for them...My Mother always talked about driving to Georgia to get married.

I don't know what county .. I have called every little county court house over the Tennessee county line.

Comment: Are you sure they got married in Georgia? If they were born in Knoxville and died in Knoxville, maybe they also got married in Knoxville. Also, a child was born in Knoxville in 1953. If they did get married in Knoxville, those records 1945-1969 are on microfilm at the State Library and Archives: https://sos.tn.gov/products/tsla/marriage-records-tennessee-state-library-and-archives . OTOH, if it was Georgia, the state page says records prior to 1952 are at the county: https://dph.georgia.gov/VitalRecords/ways-request-vital-record/marriage-records so you would have to know which county.

Comment: Where have you searched so far?

Comment: I don't know what county .. I have called every little county court house over the Tennessee county line.. my sister was born in April 1948.. in Knoxville.. I was born in 1952 in Knoxville .. all of my brothers and sisters were born in Knoxville.

Comment: As for driving over the state line to get married because they were too young, my grandparents did the same, also from Tennessee, but from Memphis to Arkansas.

Comment: This article on [Gretna Greens](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Gretna_Greens_in_the_United_States) says that Rome, Floyd County, GA was a popular place for people from TN to get married. Floyd County isn't on the border, so you may have missed that one.